Clip raster to specified extent
I want a clip a raster to a specified extent of a shapefile (polygon), I usually use clip raster tool in ArcGIS Pro, my raster cell size is 10 m and when I clip it using the tool the generated raster falls outside the clipping extent like in the image (black line is the clipping extent). I used maintain clipping extent option in clip raster tool and the raster generated aligned exactly with the clipping extent but I noticed that pixels were shifted a couple of meters. Is there any way to clip the raster to align with the clipping extent but without shifting the place of the pixels?


No, you have to choose which is  going to be preserved.

Use Snap raster option in environment settings

@FelixIP I also used it, but same thing happened

Bad luck, unless original raster and polygon are perfectly aligned

Not possible. Raster cells are always the same dimensions, you can't clip out part of a cell.  You could resample your raster to a smaller cell size to reduce the effect though.

@user2856 great idea, thank you

You can't have half a pixel.  That doesn't make sense.  So the options available to deal with this issue are all compromises.
